# Get latest entry in django in multiple dimensions

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model that looks something like this:

```
class MyModel(Model):
     field_1 = IntegerField()
     field_2 = IntegerField()
     field_3 = IntegerField()
     value = IntegerField()
     time_stamp = DateTimeField()
```

I want to find the latest entry for all sets of combinations of `(field1, field2, field3)` tuples, and grab the value of `value` from that row. 
 For example lets say the table has the following rows:

```
Field1, Field2, Field3, TimeStamp, Value
1     , 1     , 1     , 1/1/2015 , 1
1     , 1     , 1     , 1/2/2015 , 2
1     , 1     , 2     , 1/1/2015 , 3
2     , 2     , 2     , 1/1/2015 , 4
```

I would want the result of my query to return **rows** **2,3,4**

I could obviously do something like:

```
dims = MyModel.objects.values('field1', 'field2', 'field3').distinct()
for dim in dims:
    row = MyModel.objects.filter(**dim).latest('time_stamp')
    value = row.value
```

But that seems like a lot of **DB hits**, there a way to do this with fewer touches?

Comment: This might not work, but could you try: `MyModel.objects.values('field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3').distinct().annotate(latest=Max('time_stamp'))`?

Comment: @ShangWang thanks for your reply, I've edited to make my question more clear (hopefully), how can I preserve the `value` of each row with your method?

Comment: What do you mean `preserve the value of each row`? Is it related what you mentioned `all sets of combination`? Or you want to show all fields for each record?

Comment: So for each combination the tuples for `field1, field2, field3` I want to find the row that is latest (determined by `time_stamp`) and grab the `value` from that row.  Question has been updated to reflect this desire

Comment: Shot in the dark:  `MyModel.objects.values('field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3').distinct().annotate(latest=Max('time_stamp')).values('field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3', 'latest', 'value')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it in one go at the database (tested with PostGreSQL):

```
MyModel.objects.order_by('field_1__pk', 'field_2__pk', 'field_3__pk', '-time_stamp')
.distinct('field_1__pk', 'field_2__pk', 'field_3__pk')
.values('value')
```

The `order_by` groups identical `field_x`-triplets together with the latest `time_stamp` first, `distinct` then selects only the first row for each such triplet. This works for your simple model, but cautiousness is generally required when combining `order_by`, `distinct` and `values`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

**EDIT:** Updated the answer to use the pk's of the fields.  When they are not ordinary types the order_by does not work super properly.  However using the pk's gives the proper result.

Comment: I'm getting some errors that say "SELECT DISTINCT on expression must match intial ORDER BY expressions".  Even though I am doing the same order by (excluding the time stamp as you have done here).  Any input?

Comment: Was able to get it working and updated the answer, check is yours! :)

Comment: Cool ;) yeah, if they're not IntegerFields, it's more complicated.